# Element attribute selector

Tags: jointjs

I have the following markup in cell. Is it possible to select this using ID attribute of markup. I see many examples of using "class". I tried using "#actions" but it didn't work.

cell.attr({
         '#actions': {
                display: 'none'
            },
           });

```
<g id="actions" transform="translate(37.000000, 11.000000)">
            <g id="settings" transform="translate(103.000000, 0.000000)">
                <circle id="Oval" fill="#4A4A4A" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"></circle>
                <path d="M10.2857143,11.3828571  Z" id="settings-icon" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
            </g>
            <g id="delete">
                <circle id="Oval" fill="#E77087" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"></circle>
                <path d="M13.7142857, Z" id="delete-icon" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Id as a selector, If you do not want to display the cell which has id 'actions', try using CSS for #actions